# How to generate an asset-manifest.json for Vuejs exactly same as React?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I have created a fresh app using Vue CLI (PWA is enabled). I want to generate an `asset-manifest.json` file but with the exact same structure like what Create React App generates.
For example, the `asset-manifest.json` file of a fresh app created by CRA, looks like this:

[image]

But Vue doesn't generate such a file and I had to install `webpack-assets-manifest` and then by adding the following configuration to `vue.config.js` file:

[image]

I was able to make the app generate this file for me. But obviously the output looks like this:

[image]

The question here is that how I can configure my Vue app to generate this file with the exact structure of React app (generating chunks automatically, categorizing by entrypoints and files keys, as well as generating the `main.chunk.js`, `bundle.js` files, etc.)?

I am not professional at Vue and I am used to React. So, any suggestions or thoughts from experts are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to have `files` key, so I used the `transform` option like this. I also renamed `app.js` to `main.js`. This customization were enough for me, for now.

I want this to be generated during development build as well and generate `bundle.js`, but it doesn't generate this file till I run `yarn build` which I have to research on. Let me know if you have any ideas.

You can use the `entrypoints: true` to generate entrypoints key.

[image]

The generated file was like this

[image]